# How to force RPM to install files in a single directory, Is it possible?

Tags: linux, installation, rpm

rpm install command, installs files all over the place like: /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, /etc/, /usr/share

This way it's hard to figure out all the contents of the installation.
Is it possible to force rpm to install everything in a single directory?

Comment: **Don't do that**. The Linux Standard Base defines quite well, and with good reasons, where things should be. You certainly do want to have useful directories. Your system would be much more messy without any directories....

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable question to ask. OP may have an alternative partition he wants to install certain aps on.

Comment: This question is not about programming. It would belong on unix.stackexchange.com, and possibly has already been asked.

Comment: With software defined systems and networks, the line between programming questions and sys admin questions has become blurry(er).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can use the `--relocate` to change 1 directory of the install process

```
rpm -i --relocate /usr/sbin=/some/other/path/sbin packagename.rpm
```

or use `--prefix` for the whole installation process

```
rpm  -i --prefix=/some/other/path/ packagename.rpm
```

Comment: [elioliu@SWEBVM000017 ~/p]$ rpm -i --prefix=/data/elioliu/mysql/ mysql-community-server-5.7.21-1.el7.x86_64.rpm 
warning: mysql-community-server-5.7.21-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY
error: package mysql-community-server is not relocatable

Comment: the problem you have is that some packets are not relocatable but this is a problem of mysql but not true to all

see https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#Relocatable_packages

Answer (score 14):

As noted elsewhere, **don't do that**.

However, if you want to see what files will be installed where:

```
rpm -qlp packagename.rpm
```

If you want to extract them to a different root to examine them (e.g. look at configuration files, etc), *from a temporary directory*:

```
rpm2cpio /path/to/rpm/packagename.rpm | cpio -div
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron...understood your point of letting rpm install files in its chosen directories.